# What is an appropriate word for a third-tier item (primary, secondary, ...)?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, numbers

If a first-tier item is called *primary*, and a second-tier item is called *secondary*, what can third, and greater, -tier items be called?

Comment: Voting to close as general reference, this is the first Google result for "primary secondary numbering" http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/aftertertiary

Comment: I honestly didn't think to search for that.  I was looking for variations on the number 3 and thought it would be useful to know if there was an actual sequence I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Closed because "**this question is too basic**". Shut up, Stack Exchange! lol Some questions are basic in nature, and don't need to be made overly complicated. Would it please the SE gods if OP had padded the question with "intellectualism" by including a history and etymology of the word "primary" and all the others that follow in the sequence? :-) Closed or not, I'm upvoting this Q&A, for its legitimacy and usefulness as a reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The third would be called "tertiary". The [Oxford Online Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/aftertertiary) provides the rest:

> The sequence continues with quaternary, quinary, senary, septenary, octonary, nonary, and denary

Comment: Excellent, I actually thought of that but believed it to be all-encompassing; Essentially anything that wasn't primary.  I'm glad to learn that this isn't the case.

Comment: Thank you! for some reason "trinary" is all that came to mind, although I knew it was wrong, since "trinary" merely refers to a *set* of three, not an ordinal third numbering in a sequence. After some consideration, I believe that "some reason" is: while both prefixes are Latin, in English it is more common to find words with the *cardinal* **tri-** prefix than the *ordinal* **terti-** prefix. [Ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix)